# Regarding the matrix form of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

This is my first question, so I will try and make it brief.

If $V= \mathbb R^2$, let $\mathcal{B}=\{ e_1, e_2 \}$ be *any* orthonormal basis of $V$.

In class we were asked to find the matrix form, in the base $\mathcal{B}$, of the linear map $T:V \to V$ such that $T(e_j)=-Xe_j$ and $T(Xe_j)=-e_j$, for $j=1,2$. Here $X$ is the matrix $$ X=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\
1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

I would be able to find the matrix representation of $T$ if the the matrix $X$ wasn’t present, and I don’t know what to do? I thing that the matrix representation of $T$ is a permutation matrix, but I’m not sure.

Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: A linear map is completely determined by the action on the basis. $\dim(\Bbb{C})=2$ over $\Bbb{R}$ . Does $4$ formulas for $T$ necessary?

Comment: The definition you gave is inconsistent,  as noted below.

Comment: I consulted, and the question has an error, its not the imaginary unit, it is the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\
1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}. I’m going to edit it right away.

Comment: Did you copy the question correctly? Maybe it was not supposed to be one question, but two, one for $T(e_j)=-Xe_j$ and one for $T(Xe_j)=-e_j$?

Comment: @CarstenS No, sadly. The hypothesis states that $T$ satisfies both relations simultaneously. I’ll double ckeck tho…

Comment: Now that the question has been edited, I can see no mention of complex numbers at all. It seems obvious that $T$ is an $\Bbb R$-linear operator on a $2$-dimensional real vector space, not a $\Bbb C$-linear operator on a $1$-dimensional complex vector space. I'm not sure the `complex-numbers` tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

For the question as given, there is no such matrix.

Multiplying the first condition by $i$, we see that
$$i \cdot T(e_j) = (i)(-i)e_j = e_j.$$
So, by linearity we see that $T(ie_j) = e_j$, which contradicts the other condition.

**Edit:** Unless I'm missing something, it is still inconsistent. The first condition says that
$$T \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0&1 \\ -1&0\end{array} \right]\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ -1 \end{array} \right] = -e_2, \text{ and}$$
$$T \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0&1 \\ -1&0\end{array} \right]\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] = e_1.$$

That is, $T(e_1) = -e_2$ and $T(e_2) = e_1$. Considering the other condition (I'll spare you the working out), we get
$$T(Xe_1) = T(e_2) = -e_1, \text{ and }$$
$$T(Xe_2) = T(-e_1) = -e_2 \implies T(e_1) = e_2.$$

Comment: You are right, the question was wrong. I already corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

The columns of the matrix are the results of applying the transformation to the basis vectors, expressed in that basis.  We get $$\begin{pmatrix}0\quad1\\-1\quad 0\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: Sorry, the question was wrong. I already corrected it.

Comment: I know, I changed my answer in response.